# Finding the Radon Nikodym Derivative.

Tags: proof-writing, solution-verification

Here is the problem:

Let $(X, \mathfrak{M}, \mu)$ be a finite measure space, let $\{E_{k}\}_{k=1}^{n}$ a collection of measurable sets, and $\{ c_{k}\}_{k=1}^n$ a collection of real numbers. For $E \in \mathfrak{M}$ define $$\nu(E) = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{k} \mu(E \bigcap E_{k}).$$ Show that $\nu$ is a measure on $(X, \mathfrak{M})$ that is absolutely continuous with respect to $\mu$ and find its Radon-Nikodym derivative $d\nu / d\mu.$

I want to find the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$.

**My trial is**

Since the definition of the integral of a simple function $\psi$ is given by: let $c_{1}, c_{2}, ... , c_{n}$ be positive values taken by $\psi$ on X and, for $1 \leq k \leq n,$ define $E_{k} = \{ x \in X | \psi(x) = c_{k}\}.$ Define $$\int_{X} \psi d\mu = \sum_{k=1}^{n} c_{k}. \mu(E_{k}).$$

Then the given definition of $\nu$ is the integral of the simple function $\psi$, then the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ w.r.t $\mu$ is the simple function $\psi$,

**but I have a question about my trial:**  the given definition of $\nu$ in the question contains $E \bigcap E_{k}$ but the definition of the integral of a simple function contains $E_{k}$ only, so how can I deal with this?

Comment: That's because you're computing $\nu(X) = \int_X{\Psi}d\mu$, i.e. the measure on of the entire set $X$ provided $\Psi$ is the Radon-Nikodym derivative of $\nu$ wrt $\mu$. For any other measurable $E$ you'd have $\nu(E) = \int_E{\Psi}d\mu = \Sigma_{k=1}^nc_k\mu(E \cap E_k)$, provided the $E_k$ are disjoint.

Comment: From where in "Royden and Fitzpatrick "real analysis"4th edition " did you get this information , or how can we prove this @BrandonSweeting

Comment: Oh, I thought you had established that $\Psi$ was the derivative already ($\Psi$ being the simple function with the value $c_k$ on the measurable set $E_k$ from the definition of $\nu$). Was it stated that the $E_k$ are disjoint? If so, proving $\Psi$ is the derivate is a simple matter of verifying the second equality in my first comment, which just follows from the additivity of $\mu$.

Comment: No they are not as you can see from the question and the definition.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Note the Radon Nikodym derivative of the sum is the sum of the Radon Nikodym derivatives. It also respects scaling so you need only find it for $\nu_1(E)=\mu(E\cap E_1)=\int 1_E 1_{E_1}d\mu$. Thus $\frac{d\nu}{d\mu}=\sum_{i=1}^n c_i1_{E_i}$.

It is perfectly fine that the Radon Nikodym derivative doesn't reference $E$. You only need E when caluclating $\nu(E)$ but you can write down $\nu$ only referencing your preferred measurable sets.

Comment: Sorry for this stupid question, but how can we prove that "the Radon Nikodym derivative of the sum is the sum of the Radon  Nikodym derivative  " ... could you show me the proof please?

Comment: If $f$ is the RND of $\nu_1$ w.r.t. $\mu$ and $g$ is the RND of $\nu_2$ w.r.t. $\mu$ then $\int_A(f+g) d\mu=\int_A f d\mu+\int_A g  d\mu=\nu_1(A)+\nu_2 (A)=\nu(A)$ where $\nu =\nu_1+\nu_2$. By definition this says that $f+g$ is the RND of $\mu$ w.r.t. $\mu$. @Emptymind