# Understanding a part of the proof that a linear combination of 2 singular measures is a singular measure.

Tags: proof-explanation, solution-verification

Here is the problem and its solution:

> [image]
>
> [image]

**My question is:**

I do not understand, in the solution, why $$ X = (A_{1} \cap A_{2}) \cup (B_{1} \cup B_{2}),$$ Could anyone explain this for me please?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $x \notin B_1 \cup B_2$. Then $x \notin B_1$ which implies $x \in A_1$ because $X =A_1 \cup B_1$. Similarly, $x \notin B_2$ which implies $x \in A_2$ because $X =A_2 \cup B_2$. So $x \in A_1 \cap A_2$. Hence any point $x$ either belongs to $B_1 \cup B_2$ or to $A_1\cap A_2$.

Comment: Could you please look at this question (if you have time) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525244/finding-the-radon-nikodym-derivative/3525286#3525286 I am a little bit confused from the answer there, even though I admire the answer.

Comment: And could you check this one please (if you have time) https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3525273/ldt-if-measures-mu-and-nu-are-not-assumed-to-be-sigma-finite

Comment: And here, in this question, why we are sure that $(B_1 \cup B_2) \bigcap (A_1\cap A_2) = \emptyset $ ?

Comment: Yes, that is true.  If $x $ is in this intersection then $x \in B_1$ or $x \in B_2$ and this leads to a contradiction since $A_1 \cap B_1$ and $A_2 \cap B_2$ are both empty. @Emptymind